# Convert Unix timestamp to hours:minutes AM/PM?

Tags: javascript

I already convert it but the problem is I don't know how to add am/pm.

My solution

```js
var unixtimestamp = "1560994096411";
var date = new Date(unixtimestamp);
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
var convdataTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);
console.log(convdataTime);
```

I got this

> 9:28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use momentjs library for your requirement

```
var unixtimestamp = 1560994096411;
let result = moment.unix(unixtimestamp).format('hh:mm A'); // 10 digit
let result = moment(unixtimestamp).format('hh:mm A'); // 13 digit
console.log(result);
```

```js
var unixtimestamp = 1560994096411;
let result = moment(unixtimestamp).format('hh:mm A');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    function formatAMPM(UNIX_timestamp) {

        var date = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);

        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var secends = date.getSeconds();

        var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        secends = secends < 10 ? '0' + secends : secends;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + secends + ' ' + ampm;

        return strTime;
    }

    console.log(formatAMPM(1560994096));

</script>
```